# Want to call function by using if/else condition in a button (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I have a button and i want to call a particular function if a particular situation is true , if it is not true then i want to call other function .

But i want to handle above scenario in one onClick event .

I have tried this

```
<button onClick= {addTodo , handleClickOpen}> Add Todo </button>
```

I thought that first it will check addTodo function and if addTodo doesn't complete its work then handleClickOpen function will be called .

But Button doesn't perform like this.

Would you please suggest some other way ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you mean to execute handleClickOpen if addTodo returns false?

Comment: I have provided the answer below, and if you want `handleClickOpen` to be called if `addTodo` failed or something, you can simple return some value from `addTodo` to check whether to call  `handleClickOpen` or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple inline if:

```
<button onClick= {e => myBooleanCondition ? addTodo(e) : handleClickOpen(e)}> Add Todo </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you can simply call one function on `onClick` that contains the `if/else` statement.

```
const onClick = () => {
 if () { //some condition
     addTodo();
 } else {
      handleClickOpen();
   }
}

<button onClick= {onClick}> Add Todo </button>
```

The above syntax can vary as per your code standards/structure.

Comment: Don't forget to proxy the `onClick` event to the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The way i would do it is using ternary operator

```
<button onClick= {event => condition ? addTodo(event) : handleClickOpen(event)}> Add Todo </button>
```

and you can also call the second function which decides which function to operate

```
<button onClick= {event => handleClick(event)}> Add Todo </button>
```

now in your js file use this function

```
 handleClick(event){
        if(event){
             addTodo();
        }else{
             handleClickOpen();
        }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to proxy the `onClick` event to the callbacks.

Comment: as its reactjs post, so function binding can be done with the bind keyword in the constructor?? Is it necessary to bind it in onClick method, which generates a new function at every instance?

Comment: Not so much in functional components since `this` is undefined, so there's nothing really to bind a callback function to. There's the [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook to memoize callbacks if there's a performance issue.

Comment: yeah the reason i didn't used callback is that i assumed it as a class component not functional component, so i have edited my syntax according to functional component now